# MySQL query to search in between two time range between two dates using timestamp data

Tags: mysql

I have timestamp values in my db. It has values like 2014-11-25 10:30:00.
I need to get all records between two dates and that has time between certain range like between 2014-10-20 to 2014-11-25 and between 9am to 7pm..

I need the query for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use internal mysql functions for convert datetype.

I think you need DATE() and TIME() functions.

Details you can find [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query , I used it in my code for displaying data between two dates.

```
SELECT * from tablename WHERE columnname BETWEEN '2014-10-20 00:00:00' AND '2014-11-25  23:59:59'
```

The query includes start time of the particular date to end time of ending particular date.

You edit your query according to your start and end timings.

Comment: No, The requirement is start time and end time both has start and end times

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply guys. I have found the answer

SELECT * FROM alerts 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2014-11-16' AND '2014-11-26'
AND TIME(DATE) BETWEEN '09:00' AND '19:00'
 Is giving the expected result.. :-)